# Apply tkinter cursor onto the entire window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to know how to make it so the loading cursor will show up if you are hovering over any part of the window, I know how to do it for just one widget (`<Widget>(cursor="watch")`) but I do not know how to apply it to the whole window it tried to do it like `Tk(cursor="watch")` but it will just give me and error that says that it doesn't take that argument. Can someone please tell me how to do that. Thanks in advance

Python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the root cursor property with `root['cursor'] = 'watch'`

As an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("250x50")

    label_frame = tk.Frame(root)

    w = tk.Label(label_frame, text="Label UNO", bg="red", fg="white", width=8, height=2)
    w.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    w = tk.Label(label_frame, text="Label2", bg="green", fg="black", width=8, height=2)
    w.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    w = tk.Label(label_frame, text="Label DREI", bg="blue", fg="white", width=8, height=2)
    w.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    label_frame.pack()
    label_frame.pack(expand=True)

    root['cursor'] = "watch"

    root.mainloop()
```